# c# - JSON with square brackets not possible to deserialize with RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp

hopefully you can help me. I want to print the "label" of one of the elements.

JSON input:

```
[
  {
    "entity":{
      "type":"postcode",
      "id":"P11516",
      "label":"18314 Divitz-Spoldershagen",
      "value":"18314"
    },
    "matches":[
      {
        "offset":0,
        "length":5
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "entity":{
      "type":"postcode",
      "id":"P11541",
      "label":"18314 Kenz-Küstrow",
      "value":"18314"
    },
    "matches":[
      {
        "offset":0,
        "length":5
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "entity":{
      "type":"postcode",
      "id":"P11549",
      "label":"18314 Löbnitz",
      "value":"18314"
    },
    "matches":[
      {
        "offset":0,
        "length":5
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "entity":{
      "type":"postcode",
      "id":"P11551",
      "label":"18314 Lüdershagen",
      "value":"18314"
    },
    "matches":[
      {
        "offset":0,
        "length":5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And the API call with JsonDeserializer

```
public string callGACWithPLZSandbox(string plz)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://rest.sandbox-immobilienscout24.de");
    var request = new RestRequest("restapi/api/gis/v2.0/geoautocomplete/DEU", Method.GET);
    client.ClearHandlers();
    client.AddHandler("application/json", new JsonDeserializer());
    request.AddQueryParameter("i", plz);
    request.AddQueryParameter("t", "postcode");
    request.AddHeader("bla", "blub");
    IRestResponse<Rootobject> response = client.Execute<Rootobject>(request);

    return response.Data.Property1[1].entity.label;
}
```

And, the classes

```
class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

class Class1
{
    public Entity entity { get; set; }
    public Match[] matches { get; set; }
}

class Entity
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

 class Match
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Result is always "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"...

Comment: In a nutshell, your JSON represents an array, but you are deserializing into a single object.  Deserialize into a `List<Class1>` instead.

Comment: Thank you, but `return response.Data[0].entity.label;` still throws a NullReferenceException. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options either change the object you're trying to serialize to:

```
IRestResponse<List<Class1>> response = client.Execute<List<Class1>>(request);
```

Or modify your Json to

```
{
 "Property1" : [
  {
    "entity":{
      "type":"postcode",
      "id":"P11516",
      "label":"18314 Divitz-Spoldershagen",
      "value":"18314"
    },
    "matches":[
      {
        "offset":0,
        "length":5
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "entity":{
      "type":"postcode",
      "id":"P11541",
      "label":"18314 Kenz-Küstrow",
      "value":"18314"
    },
    "matches":[
      {
        "offset":0,
        "length":5
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "entity":{
      "type":"postcode",
      "id":"P11549",
      "label":"18314 Löbnitz",
      "value":"18314"
    },
    "matches":[
      {
        "offset":0,
        "length":5
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "entity":{
      "type":"postcode",
      "id":"P11551",
      "label":"18314 Lüdershagen",
      "value":"18314"
    },
    "matches":[
      {
        "offset":0,
        "length":5
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

If you modify your json leave the serializing call as you have it now.

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PLZCounter.callGACWithPLZSandbox (System.String plz) (at Assets/PLZCounter.cs:63)
PLZCounter.Update () (at Assets/PLZCounter.cs:47)

Comment: Okay, I cannot change the JSON. But if I change the object like this 
    return response.Data[0].entity.label;

Comment: Omg, I hate this "enter" behaviour...

Okay, I cannot change the JSON. But if I change the object as you told me like this 

    return response.Data[0].entity.label;

I still get a NullReferenceException. Any other idea?